# project references another project why does it have to rebuilt

Tags: visual-studio, dll, msbuild, .net-assembly

One of the points with component oriented software is that metadata has replaced linking.

This means that in the absence of strong naming and versioning of assemblies changing and recompiling an assembly **B** that is referenced by an assembly **A** should not require the recompilation of **A**.

But this is what happens is Visual Studio!

The output window contains the text "B.dll" is newer than output file "A.dll" so it stems from the target definition and moreover the assembly A.dll is actually changed.

I would like to know the reason for this and what is changed in A.dll. Looking at the old and new versions of A.dll in IL Spy they look identical.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what you changed in `B` so assumes you have introduced public interface changes and just rebuilds `A` to be on the safe side. Of course if you didn't change the public interface, `A` might remain unchanged. You can introduce an assembly `C` which just holds the interface and then only `B` needs to be rebuilt when implementation changes.

Comment: Typically A needs to create objects (implementations) of classes in B and thus needs to reference B anyway. If one introduces a factory the factory needs to reference B and A needs to reference the factory i.e one gets an depency of instantiation that cant be broken unless one uses some kind of reflection - dependeny injection - Ninject or so.